# How to get token after login into keycloak with python-keycloak

Tags: python, flask, oauth, keycloak

I am using **flask** to build app and **keycloak** for authorization.

```
from flask import Flask, session, request
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenID

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 's_k'


keycloak_open_id =  KeycloakOpenID(server_url="http://localhost:8080/auth/",
                        client_id="Centrum",
                        realm_name="myrealm",
                        client_secret_key="c_k")

def login_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):

    // validate token

        return func('2', *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    url = keycloak_open_id.auth_url('http://localhost:5555/auth')

    # how to get a token and assign it to session['token']?

    return redirect(url, code=302)

@app.route('/home')
@login_required
def home():
    return 'Base URL!'
```

When I am logged in and can go to /home, but without token the application always needs to go through keycloak's method. Is there any other posibility to get token other than making own login form and pass login and password into *keycloak_open_id.token(login, password)* method?

Answer (score -2):

Seems that you're looking for `grant_type=password` oauth flow, you can check [keycloak's doc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#flows) how to do it.

Basically:

```
curl \
  -d "client_id=myclient" \
  -d "client_secret=40cc097b-2a57-4c17-b36a-8fdf3fc2d578" \
  -d "username=user" \
  -d "password=password" \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

Comment: He was looking for a way to get token after logging from login page, here you are giving username and password in the request